# spring security,spring with jsf project user activity tracker

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jsf-2

I would like to add a user activity tracker for my project.
The project uses Spring with JSF as view. Any idea how to add spring AOP in JSF backing bean?

I have a Spring based application, and I'm currently writing a custom annotation to track user activities including time. I have started with a  custom annotation @Timed to track the method execution time. Below is the code snippet:

**Custom annotation**

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {

}
```

**LoggingAspect**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect  {


    @Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
    public Object logExcecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{

        Object value=null;
        long currentTimeInMillisec=Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
        value=joinPoint.proceed();
        Long executionTime=(Instant.now().toEpochMilli())-currentTimeInMillisec;

        System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature() + " executed in " + executionTime + "ms");
        return value;

    }
```

**Test main class**

```
    @Component
public class TestRunAnnotation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-aspect-config.xml");


test();

    }



    @LogExecutionTime
    private static void test() {
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            i++;
            System.out.println("print value of i"+i);
        }

    }

}
```

**In xml config**

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="...">
        </context:component-scan>
          <!-- Enable @AspectJ annotation support  -->
        <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />


   <!-- Logging Aspect -->
    <bean id="loggingAspect" class="......LoggingAspect" />
     <bean id="testRunAnnotation" class="....TestRunAnnotation" />

      <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

     <tx:annotation-driven/>
  </beans>
```

While running the main method, I am not getting any message from the logging interceptor to track the execution time.

Comment: JSF can use spring managed beans instead of jsf managed ones. In the former  you can easilly use spring aop I would guess

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution ,its working for me now.

Problem in my code: in my code above i called annotation in a private method and dint use the a spring managed bean to call this method.I did the below changes to make it work,

```
@Component
public class TestRunAnnotation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-aspect-config.xml");



TestRunAnnotation test=(TestRunAnnotation) context.getBean("testRunAnnotation");
test.test();

    }



    @LogExecutionTime
    public  void test() {
        for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
            i++;
            System.out.println("print value of i"+i);
        }

    }

}
```